# Syslog server not displaying sonic wall firewall logs

Tags: centos, firewall, syslog, rsyslog, sonicwall

We have configured syslog in sonic wall firewal... in firewall packets are forwarding to syslog server that is centos
but in the syslog server we are unable to  findout where the logs have been stored.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to know where CentOs stores the syslog messages?  If so, check:

/var/log
/var/log/messages

Comment: Can you mark this as an answer so I can get credit for it, please?